# importing CSV file to database not working asp

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, csv

I am trying to import an CSV file into the database using asp, this code is from http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Import-Upload-CSV-file-data-to-SQL-Server-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

```
try
{
    //Upload and save the file
    string csvPath = Server.MapPath("/upload/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload2.SaveAs(csvPath);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)) }
    );

    string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);
    foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
            {
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TOP2000_IAO4B_GROEP5ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            //Set the database table name
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[Customers]";
            con.Open();
            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex);
}
```

However, when i go into debug mode and i look what the value of string csvData is, it's an empty string :/ I'm wondering what causes this, because obviously no data is inserted this way.

this is the CSV

```
1,John Hammond,United States
2,Mudassar Khan,India
3,Suzanne Mathews,France
4,Robert Schidner,Russia
```

the CSV is really simple to make it easy, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Check your path for the file.

Comment: i uploaded the CSV from C:\Test and from visualstudio/upload and neither are working

Comment: However, when i go into debug mode and i look what the value of string
csvData is, it's an empty string => Does this mean you are unable to read data from the file?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned on debug you see `CsvData`,  I suspect the problem lies on `csvData.Split('\n')` statement.

I just modified that particular logic, should work for you.

```
try
{      
    //Upload and save the file
    string csvPath = Server.MapPath("/upload/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload2.SaveAs(csvPath);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                                           new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                                           new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)) });

    foreach (string row in File.ReadAllLines(csvPath))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
            {
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TOP2000_IAO4B_GROEP5ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            //Set the database table name
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[Customers]";
            con.Open();
            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            con.Close();
        }
    }      

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex); 
}
```

Comment: the problem was the laptop, i have the EXACT same code, and it works on my laptop, but it does not on another, do you have any idea how that might be possible? i was thinking about permissions or something, wasn't the code after all

Comment: Are there any *exceptions/errors* you notice when running in other laptop?

Comment: nevermind... his CSV file didnt contain any data.. you would think he'd check that.. i litteraly facepalmed, and now i am making a fool out of myself aswell

Answer (score 0):

I guess your issue is with Splitting CSV data. 
Try this code working code :

```
 private string[] SplitString(string inputString)
 {
      System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions options = ((System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline)
                        | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     Regex reg = new Regex("(?:^|,)(\\\"(?:[^\\\"]+|\\\"\\\")*\\\"|[^,]*)", options);
     MatchCollection coll = reg.Matches(inputString);
     string[] items = new string[coll.Count];
     int i = 0;
     foreach (Match m in coll)
     {
        items[i++] = m.Groups[0].Value.Trim('"').Trim(',').Trim('"').Trim();
     }
      return items;
 }
```